# How to make a preloader block disappear after N seconds with React

Tags: reactjs

The output of code after the React Preloader is not being displayed. Only the preloader keeps on showing up

I have already tried checking the script,it's running Fine!

```
  export default class Nav extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="preloader">
          <div>
            <div className="spinner">
              <div className="double-bounce1" />
              <div className="double-bounce2" />
            </div>
            <span>Wait, please...</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* /Preloader */}
        {/* Top Search Area Start */}
        <div className="top-search-area">
          <div className="modal fade" id="searchModal" tabIndex={-1} role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
              <div className="modal-content">
                <div className="modal-body">
                  {/* Close Button */}
                  <button type="button" className="btn close-btn" data-dismiss="modal"><i className="fa fa-times" /></button>
                  {/* Form */}
                  <form action="index.html" method="post">
                    <input type="search" name="top-search-bar" className="form-control" placeholder="Type keywords and hit enter..." />
                    <button type="submit">Search</button>
                  </form>
                  {/* Search Button */}
                  <div className="search-btn"><i className="icon_search" /></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* Top Search Area End */}
        {/* Social Share Area Start */}
        <div className="razo-social-share-area">
          <a href="#" className="facebook"><i className="fa fa-facebook" /></a>
          <a href="#" className="twitter"><i className="fa fa-twitter" /></a>
          <a href="#" className="pinterest"><i className="fa fa-pinterest" /></a>
          <a href="#" className="instagram"><i className="fa fa-instagram" /></a>
          <a href="#" className="youtube"><i className="fa fa-youtube-play" /></a>
          <a href="#" className="ss-close-btn"><i className="arrow_right" /></a>
        </div>
        {/* Social Share Area End */}
        {/* Header Area Start */}
        <header className="header-area">
          {/* Main Header Start */}
          <div className="main-header-area">
            <div className="classy-nav-container breakpoint-off">
              <div className="container">
                {/* Classy Menu */}
                <nav className="classy-navbar justify-content-between" id="razoNav">
                  {/* Logo */}
                  <a className="nav-brand" href="index.html"><img src="./img/core-img/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
                  {/* Navbar Toggler */}
                  <div className="classy-navbar-toggler">
                    <span className="navbarToggler"><span /><span /><span /></span>
                  </div>
                  {/* Menu */}
                  <div className="classy-menu">
                    {/* Menu Close Button */}
                    <div className="classycloseIcon">
                      <div className="cross-wrap"><span className="top" /><span className="bottom" /></div>
                    </div>
                    {/* Nav Start */}
                    <div className="classynav">
                      <ul id="nav">
                        <li><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pages</a>
                          <ul className="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="./index.html">- Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="./charts.html">- Charts</a></li>
                            <li><a href="./single-charts.html">- Charts Details</a></li>
                            <li><a href="./podcast.html">- Podcast</a></li>
                            <li><a href="./single-podcast.html">- Podcast Details</a></li>
                            <li><a href="./show.html">- Show</a></li>
                            <li><a href="./events.html">- Event</a></li>
                            <li><a href="./blog.html">- Blog</a></li>
                            <li><a href="./single-blog.html">- Blog Details</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">- Dropdown</a>
                              <ul className="dropdown">
                                <li><a href="#">- Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">- Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">- Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">- Dropdown Item</a></li>
                              </ul>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
```

App.js which is in 'root' is as follows-

```
import Nav from './Nav';
import Main from './Components/Main'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav/>
        <Main /> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}





export default App;
```

The nav-bar and the main-page component should have been rendered but nothing is rendered just preloader showing up till infinite time.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, could you edit your answer with the whole code involved? As it stands, there is no functional code to study in your question and one cannot guess how the preloader could disappear

Comment: i have edited it.

Comment: Ok so there's definitely nothing in the code that I see to stop the preloader from showing. When do you expect it to stop showing? The css could help too.

Comment: after a delay of 10secs or so

Comment: I'd like to help, but it is really unclear what it is about. Are you trying to use some NPM library? Please try to organize it - your source code first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the preloader to disappear after a fixed amount of time you can use a combination of [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount), [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) and [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-does-setstate-do):

```
    export default class Nav extends Component {
        state = {
            preloading: true
        }
        componentDidMount() {
            // turns preloading off 10 seconds after the component has mounted
            setTimeout(
                () => this.setState(() => ({ preloading: false })),
                10000
            );

        }

        render() {
            const { preloading } = this.state;
            return (
                <div>
                    {preloading &&
                    <div id="preloader">
                        <div>
                            <div className="spinner">
                                <div className="double-bounce1" />
                                <div className="double-bounce2" />
                            </div>
                            <span>Wait, please...</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    }
                    {/* /Preloader */}
                ....
            }
        }
```